# How to open python file (file1) using another python file (file2), but the name file2 is the string from the text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have python file (file1) and (file2) both in the same directory and one text file (ABC.txt) containing the string as 'file1' in the first line, also  kept in the same directory. Now I want to import file1 from file2 but not like we usually do (import file1), instead I want to open it through the text file string.

This is something what I want to do:

```
#####file2.py####

ABC=open('ABC.txt', 'r')
line= ABC.readlines()

import line[0] ##### the first line of ABC.txt is the file1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html)

```
import importlib

ABC=open('ABC.txt', 'r')
line= ABC.readlines()

importlib.import_module(line[0])
```